# Getting typecast errors in xcode5.1

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have the following compiler error in xcode5.1

[www.imgur.com/xiGxhBh](http://www.imgur.com/xiGxhBh)

[www.imgur.com/tA2PGs0](http://www.imgur.com/tA2PGs0)

[www.imgur.com/u5RSoHA](http://www.imgur.com/u5RSoHA)

[www.imgur.com/Ycq7l0s](http://www.imgur.com/Ycq7l0s)

[www.imgur.com/KrFP0OQ](http://www.imgur.com/KrFP0OQ)

pls. suggest fix for these 5 issues. These are some simple type casting issues. I can fix them on my own but I need to know how to do it.waiting for your reply.

Comment: add images link properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need 64bit precision, most of those warnings should go away if you cast them to int.

For example, from your first screenshot: `_flags.numColumns = (int) [gridData numberOfItemsPerRow]`